# Move multiple files with same name in same directory

Tags: command-line, files, mv

I have a directory with multiple files of same name.

```
../directory ls
File.txt
File.txt
File1.txt
```

How can I move all files to a new directory (/new) using mv

```
../new ls
File.txt
File.txt
File1.txt
```

Update:
The files are being FTPed to an UNIX directory by a source system, which needs to be processed using shell script. Once done I need to move multiple instances of the same file (if any) to an Archive directory.

And by "processed" all I am doing is Copying it to one Dir. And Archive in another using MV. Using cp n mv only one instance of the file is being processed.

Comment: Thanks @icarus. Have updated the description with a detailed scenario.

Comment: Ah, so does this mean that you have a fixed name, e.g. results, which is being pushed in via FTP, and you need to move this to a variable filename like Archive/results.2016.11.27.1315 ?

Comment: Yes. I need to handle multiple instances of the file (which does has a fixed name). Say suppose I have input.txt with 10 EMP details and I unable to process the data. When the next set of file comes with the same name, I am able to move only one file for processing. The most recent one.

Comment: Because you have a fixed filename, the FTP process will overwrite the previous `input.txt`, so you will only have a single file called `input.txt` at a time (which will be the most recent one).

Answer (score 1):

> I have a directory with multiple files of same name.

Well, you shouldn't. How can you even `cat` their contents? (that is, without getting only the first file of the same name each time).

> How can I move all files to a new directory (/new) using mv ../new ls File.txt File.txt File1.txt

I'd settle for trying to give them different names:

```
mv File.txt ../new/File.txt.1
mv File.txt ../new/File.txt.2
```

and see if you end up with distinct files that way.

> Update: The files are being FTPed to an UNIX directory by a source system, which needs to be processed using shell script.

This is overwhelmingly unlikely to result in a situation in which you have multiple files with the same name in the same directory. So don't sweat that case, I guess.

Comment: The files are being FTPed to an UNIX directory by a source system, which needs to be processed using shell script. Once done I need to move multiple instances of the same file (if any) to an Archive directory.

Comment: @Dudul Please update your question with more details of this process.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I hope this makes it clearer. Should had put in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use a wildcard to move it all e.g.

```
mv file.tx* /new/
```

This will move all files that have a name that starts with `file.tx` to your directory `/new`. It will leave behind any files that don't match, so `file1.txt` will stay in the directory. If you want to move any file with name file.txt and file1.txt you could move your wildcard * to after file e.g. `file*` this will then move any file in that directory that has a name starting with file.